# Difference of column value received from operation done on 2 different files

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have following 2 files file1.txt and file2.txt with the data as given below-

Data in file1.txt
125
125
295
295
355
355
355

Data in file2.txt
125
125
295
355

I did below operation over the files and got following output-

Operation1-
sort file1.txt | uniq -c
   2 125
   2 295
   3 355

Operation2-
sort file2.txt | uniq -c
   2 125
   1 295
   1 355

Now, I want following output using the result of Operation1 and Operation2 -
I want to compare the result of Operation1 and Operation2  and get the output which will show the difference of values from column 1 of both the files, and it will show the column 2 as it is as given below-

0 125
1 295
2 355

Answer (score 1):

redirect output of operation 1 and operation 2 in some files. Let say

> file1

and

> file2

, then write like this:-

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1-$3,$2}'
```

you will have output

```
0 125
1 295
2 355
```

Comment: If I don't want to include those line in the output where the difference is 0 (e.g 0 125), then what can be done?